# Sony Xperia Pro is stuck in bootloop. How to fix?

Tags: reboot, unbricking, boot-loop

Yesterday, my rooted Xperia Pro decided to go into perpetual restart mode. I tried removing the SIM and SD cards to no avail. I tried reflashing the ICS upgrade. I tried throwing my phone across the room. (Well, OK, so I haven't tried that yet.)

#### What exactly happens

1. I turn on the phone.
2. The Sony logo comes up.

   [image: Sony Logo]
3. It lights up for 1/2 of a second. I cannot get into recovery mode ever since I reflashed the ICS upgrade.

   [image: Sony Logo bright]
4. The Xperia logo comes up.

   [image: Xperia Logo 1]
5. The phone vibrates very briefly. (Like a haptic feedback vibrate.)

   [image: Xperia Logo 2]
6. The lockscreen used to flash for one second before I tried reflashing the ICS upgrades. Now, it just shows a gray background with the status bar.

   [image]
7. The phone reboots one second after the status bar appears.

#### Other information

Recently, my battery would randomly go from 70% to near 10% in a few hours or so while it was in my pocket. (As opposed to the regular 1%/hour rate.) Sometimes, it would open up the status bar or unlock my lockscreen. I had an OTA notification in my status bar -- it's possible this might have been selected accidentally.

Answer (score 1):

So I guess the problem was either fixed or not solved.
But Just if anyone has the same problem it may be nice to know the solution.
I had the same problem and when I done the flashing the android would just start for around a second. We are using stock here, if you get a bootloop with an unlocked bootloader you should use fastboot to install a recovery or use the recovery.

So first you need to get Flashtool and find the right Firmware(ftf) for the phone.
I haven't found the exact same as I had before but It worked.

So when I first tried to flash it wouldn't let me I was getting a loader.sin error.So I Built a new ftf in Flashtool and removed loader.sin.
After that it flashed and started for a second just like yours.

After I did the same again an wiped all data it worked again.

Comment: Dear Master Witcher, I'd sent in this phone for repair but they claimed it was water damage (which makes some sense since I do remember spilling a bit of water on it).